# Update remediation function value in Sonarqube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Where can we update remediation function of our rules in Sonarqube 6.7? We have Governance commercial plugin and want to validate and update these for each of the rules in our quality profile. Basically I am looking for something like below which was available till Sonarqube 4.x.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there's no more UI to update the rules remediation function, but it's still possible to use web service [api/rules/update](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/rules/update) with parameters :

- remediation_fn_type
- remediation_fn_base_effort
- remediation_fy_gap_multiplier

Comment: @julien-l-sonarsource-team Any reason why there is no more GUI? Will this feature be removed?

Comment: For the moment, there's no plan to add a UI on it, neither there's plan to remove the feature.

Comment: @Julien-L-SonarSource-Team: Thank you very much for details. But I do not think remediation function can be standardized this way for all organization as it depends purely on maturity and quality needs of development teams in that organization. It would be very convenient to have this feature back.